# Add class depending on top-position value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tooltips set on top of an image. When the user clicks one of these tooltips a content opens to reveal some info.

I'd like to slide open the content up or down, depending where the tooltip is positioned (absolute). So, I'm trying to get the "top"-value and if it's larger than 50, add a class and sort out the rest with CSS.

The problem is I'm always just getting the "top"-value of the first element. Now I tried to add an each function, which leaves me with what seems to be the average value of all the tooltips' top positions?

```
$( ".tooltip" ).each(function() {
  var toppos = $(".tooltip").css("top");
  if ( parseInt(toppos) >= 50 ) {
    $(this).addClass('higher');
  }
});
```

I'm either using each wrong, or each is not what I should be going for here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the current tooltip instead of all tooltips:

```
$( ".tooltip" ).each(function() {
  var toppos = $(this).css("top");// Use $(this) instead of $('.tooltip')
  if ( parseInt(toppos) >= 50 ) {
    $(this).addClass('higher');
  }
});
```

---

You may also try offset().top instead of css('top'):

```
var toppos = $(this).offset().top;
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thanks!

Re your second suggestion: Doesn't offset look for the position in relation to the document?